# Is there a way to explain torque and Euler's Laws of Motion from Newton's Laws

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

If I have a rigid rod and I apply a force $\vec F$ distance $r$ away from the centre of mass the torque on the rod is $\vec r \times \vec F$ from the centre of mass and the torque causes the rod to have a proportional angular acceleration.

So could the laws
$$\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F, \quad \vec \tau = I \vec \alpha$$

be explained by looking at each point in the rod which obey Newton's Laws and are pulling at each other through intermolecular forces?

Comment: 1. Please use MatJax for your formulas the next time you post a question. This time, I have corrected them. Please check, if my edit meets your intentions.  2. What have you tried to answer this question by yourself?

Comment: @Hyperon, Ok thank you for the edit. I was not sure what to try to proceed with this question.

Comment: try to have a look here: https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamics_newton_eoms_point.html (point), https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamics_newton_eoms_points.html (system of points), https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamics_newton_eoms_rigid.html (rigid systems) for the equations of motion, starting from Newton principles. And here https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/main.html for a map of classical mechanics (some links may be not working, but with some trials you can find anything)

Comment: @244529 Here you can find equivalent expressions of dynamical quantities for mechanical systems https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamical_quantities.html, https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamical_quantities_rigid_discrete.html (rigid discrete systems), https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamical_quantities_rigid_continuous.html (rigid continuous systems), and their time derivatives https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamical_quantities_rigid_derivatives.html